# Keep right angles in line connecting objects in OmniGraffle

Tags: macos, omnigraffle

Two part question, about connector lines.

Can I draw a line connecting objects that automatically breaks with right angle turns?

If not, I can manually create breaks while drawing a connector line by making single clicks. If going this route, is there a way to keep the breaks at 90-degree right angles?

Basically the same question as [this one](https://superuser.com/q/628577) but about OmniGraffle rather than PowerPoint.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the line orthogonal. From [OmniGraffle's "Drawing Basics" page](https://support.omnigroup.com/documentation/omnigraffle/mac/7.17/en/drawing-basics/):

> To create an orthogonal line … , click
> the line to select it and use the **Line** inspector to change the line
> type to **Orthogonal**.

[image]

That will change the first line below into the second.

[image]

Right click on the line and select **Add Midpoint** to control precisely where those 90 degree turns will be.